# How to apply a script to all files in extension and change names accordingly?

Tags: python, for-loop, rename, cycle, batch-rename

I have a script which does a certain transformation to a file.

```
pipeline.load_files('txt', '1.txt')
pipeline.transform('function0','file.jpg', '1.txt')
pipeline.write('txt', 'result.txt', opt={'c':None})
pipeline.score(function='function1', file ='file.jpg')
pipeline.score(function='function2', file ='file.jpg')
pipeline.write_csv('result.csv')
```

Now I want to use this script for all 100 txt files (1.txt-100.txt) in my folder. So in the end I should have 100 files named 'result1.csv'...'result100.csv' and 'result1.txt'....'result100.txt'. How can I do this? I know it has to be a for cycle loop, but I'm not sure how to change filenames.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use formatted strings

```
import glob, os

os.chdir("PUT.YOUR.DIRECTORY.CONTAINING.TEXT.FILES.HERE")
for i, file in enumerate(glob.glob("*.txt")):
    ...
    pipeline.load_files('txt', file)
    ...
    pipeline.write('txt', f'result{i+1}.txt', opt={'c':None})
    ...
    pipeline.write_csv(f'result{i+1}.csv')
```

Comment: '1.txt' in second line and 'result.txt' also have to be changed

Comment: so you want to read files 1-100.txt and then dump it as csv with name result1-100.csv right?

Comment: @lemontree please check my updated answer

Comment: >so you want to read files 1-100.txt and then dump it as csv with name result1-100.csv right

Yes. But 1.txt-100.txt is an example. What i need is something like 'for i in *.txt'.

Comment: `for i in *.txt` what do you mean, didn't get you. Do you want to get list of all txt files? or get count of it and then loop through?

Comment: I want to run the code for all *txt files in directory

Comment: @lemontree please check my updated answer

Comment: @lemontree did my answer work for you

Comment: @lemontree glad, I could help you